# Powers of two and three formula

Tags: number-theory

I have the following formula:
$$L= \frac{3^a +\sum_{i=1}^a  3^{a-i} 2^{ r_{i} }   }{ 2^{b}- 3^{a+1}  } ,$$ where
$$0<r_{1}<r_{2}<\dots<r_a<b.$$
My question is:

> Can $L$ be a natural number greater than $1?$

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Comment: This looks like it might be an interesting question! But (i) you should tell us where this strange formula came from, to get us interested; and (ii) you should tell us what _you_ think the answer is, and why.

Comment: I can only tell you that it's inspired by a notorious problem, and I think the answer is no, because I've checked a lot of numbers.

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to solve Syracuse conjecture, good luck !

Comment: :))))))))))))))